# AnkhSvn: How to revert the revert operation itself?

Tags: svn, ankhsvn

I have *(had)* working copy (SVN), instead of `Commit` I have clicked `Revert` then Ok (please don't comment this).

I know that Tortoise SVN, when reverting, moves files to Windows Trash. Do AnkhSvn does similar thing? (They are not in Trash, but maybe in some `temp` folder?)

My `bin` folder isn't in subversion so I can decompile my code and get it back in some matter.

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2014? Please, upvote it then. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you've lost reverted changes. See [SVNBook | `svn revert`](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/revert/):

> **`svn revert`** is inherently dangerous, since its entire purpose is to
>   throw away data—namely, your uncommitted changes. *Once you've
>   reverted, Subversion provides no way to get back those uncommitted
>   changes.*

BTW, the option [`Use recycle bin when reverting`](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-revert.html) in TortoiseSVN is *optional*, so it can be disabled (and can be missing in other client implementations).

Comment: I ended up using JetBrains dotPeek for recover part of my code. Thanks anyway.